# Qual a diferença de prop e emit em vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Eu sei que prop é do componente pai para o filho e emit é do filho para o pai. Mas gostaria de um exemplo do uso dos dois para eu conseguir entender melhor o conceito!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Uma propriedade é um atributo personalizado para passar informação a partir do pai. Um filho deve declarar explicitamente o que ele espera receber usando a opção props:

**- Cria o template com um `h3` e passa o *props* `title`.**

```
Vue.component('blog-post', {
   props: ['title'],
   template: '<h3>{{ title }}</h3>'
})
```

**- No template pai**

```
new Vue({
   el: "#app",
   data() {
      return {
         message: 'hello mr. magoo'
      }
   }
});
```

**- Resultará no HTML:**

```
<blog-post :title="message"></blog-post>
<!-- message está sendo renderizado no Html através do props title -->
```

---

> Um componente pai pode ouvir eventos emitidos do componente filho usando o `v-on` diretamente no template onde o componente filho é usado:

**- Cria o template com um `button` já com o método de incrementar atrelado com o `v-on:click`**

```
Vue.component('button-counter', {
   template: '<button v-on:click="incrementCounter">{{ counter }}</button>',
   data: function () {
      return {
         counter: 0
      }
   },
   methods: {
      incrementCounter: function () {
         this.counter += 1
         this.$emit('increment')
      }
   },
})
```

**- No template pai**

```
new Vue({
   el: '#counter-event-example',
   data: {
      total: 0
   },
   methods: {
      incrementTotal: function () {
         this.total += 1
      }
   }
})
```

**- Resultará no HTML:**

```
<div id="counter-event-example">
   <p>{{ total }}</p>
   <button-counter v-on:increment="incrementTotal"></button-counter>
   <button-counter v-on:increment="incrementTotal"></button-counter>
</div>
```

> **Observe que agora o template pai é atualizado na variável `total` através do botão e do método no componente filho que está sendo transmitido pelo `this.$emit('increment')`**.

**Fontes:** [vue.org](https://br.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html) - [css.tricks](https://css-tricks.com/intro-to-vue-2-components-props-slots/) - [vue.jsBrasil-facebook](https://www.facebook.com/groups/vuejsbr/?fref=nf).

*Este terceiro link é de um grupo no Facebook, recomendo muito vc participar, os cara sabem muito e sempre ajudam, não tem um post que fica sem resposta lá, aqui no Stackoverflow ainda é pequeno o suporte ao **VUE***.

Comment: Então, eu to perguntando essas coisas que eu ja meio que sei aqui exatamente para começar a ter mais coisas de vue aqui. Para que quando alguém tiver alguma dúvida procurar no google, não vai para um grupo no face, vem para o stackoverflow.

Comment: E quanto a resposta, é isso mesmo. Valeu pela explicação :D

Comment: Ah legal, boa idéia, acho que irei fazer o mesmo.

Answer (score 1):

O próprio [`v-model`](https://br.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Componentes-Suportando-v-model) é um bom exemplo para a sua pergunta.

O v-model é um "açúcar sintático" que utiliza uma `prop` chamada por padrão de `value` para passar informações para o componente filho, e um evento chamado por padrão de `input` para informar que houveram modificações no `value`

```
Vue.component('currency-input', {
  template: '\
    <span>\
      $\
      <input\
        ref="input"\
        v-bind:value="value"\
        v-on:input="updateValue($event.target.value)">\
    </span>\
  ',
  props: ['value'], // prop value
  methods: {
    updateValue: function (value) {
      //...
      // Emite o valor do número através do evento de input
      this.$emit('input', value)
    }
  }
})
```

O código acima define um componente que receberá uma `prop` chamada `value` e sempre que houver uma modificação, um evento chamado `input` será levantado para o componente pai, informando a ele que uma modificação foi realizada para a prop `value`.

O componente pai por sua vez pode utilizar este evento para atualizar o valor de `value`, como no seguinte exemplo:

```
<currency-input
  :value="something"
  @input="value => { something = value }">
</currency-input>
```